# SQL Server CE & C# After deleting records cannot read data in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have created a database file that updates readings every minute and stores in a SQL Server CE database file. However as the database gets very large, it starts to get really slow.

I decided to delete the oldest files once the database reaches a certain size as they are of no use to me. I managed to do this using the following commands:

```
command.Append("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP(" + difference.ToString() + ") ID From MyTable)");
```

where `difference.ToString()` is value I used to calculate how much I want to delete.

This worked successfully as I could open the file using `CompactView` and also I could type in the commands in `CompactView` to give the same results.

Now my problem started when I tried to read the data and update it on to a graph. So my codes in another form does the following:

```
private void updateGraphTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection))
        {
            // some code that is not relevant between these two statements
            using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
            {
                StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
                command.Clear();
                command.Append("SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID DESC");

                using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(command.ToString(), connection))
                {
                    int value = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
                    graphPage.latestID = value;

                    if (value > graphPage.startID)
                    {
                        DataColumn xDateColumn;
                        xDateColumn = new DataColumn("XDate");
                        xDateColumn.DataType = typeof(double);
                        table.Columns.Add(xDateColumn);

                        adapter.Fill(graphPage.startID, value, table);
```

The problem I have is that the table is empty, even though value from `(int)com.ExecuteScalar()` returns a value! If I did not perform the delete, it all works fine!

I cannot figure out what is happening! The only thing I can think of is something to do with reading and writing the sql file.

Much appreciated!

Comment: your saying when you the run the delete the table shows empty ?

Comment: how and when are you running the delete? is it a batch manual process or is it run automatically by another thread? it seems there could be a synch problem

Comment: There are 2 timers on separate forms, 1 timer is used to populate the database with the latest data and it runs all the time.  The other timer is used when the graphing programme is initiated. They both update the data every minute or quicker.  When the database becomes large the oldest data is deleted.  Meanwhile the graphing programme tries to update the readings to display by reading the same database.  Eventhough getting the latest ID field works and gives correct readings, when I fill the table it shows nothing.  Cheers

Comment: so your questions are: why is my table empty? And why if I execute a select query from it with ExecuteScalar am I getting a result?

Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the update-timer and running only the reader from an empty table? This will clear if the problem is related to interaction between threads or not...

Comment: Yes you are correct I get the correct result for ExecuteScalar that returns the value of the ID field (Primary Key auto increment value), however after that when I try to view the table I get nothing.  I will try what you suggested and there are a couple of other things that I will try!  I have to try solve this by some kind of process of elimination! Cheers

Comment: You need to synchronize the two db accesses. Lets say TOP ID is 10, then the cleanup deletes top 8 values and the graphing part has just calculated the top ID is 10, then you acceess data that is deleted. Best would be to do the cleanup in the graphing part before reading dat that has deleted in between.

Answer (score 0):

Better not use TOP here. As ID is incremented automatically, get the highest ID and then delete at max before that ID as the latest ID is used in the graphing part. For example, delete everything below current max ID or below max ID - 10 or so.

DELETE * from table where ID < MAX(ID);

If using TOP as you do in the delete, all values, including the TOP (last ID) is deleted. And in the graphing part you are accessing the last ID too.

Comment: Thanks but the delete works, it deletes the oldest records and not the latest records. I for example delete say 100 records out of 400.  So the actual statement works, as the ExecuteScalar is returning the correct id but showing no data.

Comment: I have found another problem! Which may be related to what you are saying.  When I do a delete, then it inserts records it inserts the new data at the top of the database rather than the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

So you have two problems:

1. your table is empty after the delete
2. your query returns a result in spite of the fact that the table is empty

Regarding the first one the problem is in your delete statement: **for some reason your `difference` value is higher or equal to the number of rows in your table and will delete the overall table**.
I would look at the way you are computing it.
In any case if you have an insert_date on your table I would change the delete statement like this to delete rows older than 10 days from today:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID From MyTable where insert_date < DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
```

The second problem is a concurrency issue related to the fact that two threads are working: **it may happens that you read data (and data are available) just before data are deleted; so you are not really getting a query result from an empty table also if this is the impression.**

Comment: Thanks, the difference value is not higher than the number of rows in the table, I have stepped through the code, I have even exited the software and looked at the database using CompactView to look at the data and it does delete the correct amount, it just seems not to show the data on the table, however does identify the correct ID.

Comment: @aaz: is it only an issue on the select statement you are running on compact view then?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem!  Forgive me if you tried to explain this to me and I didn't get it but here goes!  The problem is with populating the table whilst the value returned from ExecuteScalar is correct, that Id is greater than the table as the table counts from 0 rather than the subtracted amount!

So for example I deleted 1000 records from 5000, the oldest record would then be 1000, so when I fill the table the 5000 is the latest id, however I am trying to access the 5000th record in the table rather than the 4000th value which contains ID 5000!

I will try and rewrite the code take this into account, this was never a problem before as when I wasn't deleting they matched. D'OH!